# Firebase not working with iPhone 6s on iOS 11

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ios11

I'm writing an app that makes use of beacons, notifications, and Firebase Realtime Database. The app deployment target is iOS 11 and I'm testing it with Xcode 9.0 beta 1 (build 9M136h). In the app, I'm trying to attach a listener to get the list of beacons in my area, e.g.:

```
let db = Database.database().reference()
db.child("beacons").observe(.value) { (snap) in
        // etc...
}
```

The completion handler is correctly executed in the iPhone 7 simulator it but never succeeds on the iPhone 6s simulator (with iOS 11 beta 1) and on a real iPhone 6s (with iOS 11 beta 5).

Why this strange behavior? Could it be caused by the legacy version of Xcode?

In the log of the iPhone 6s, I only see messages about Firebase Analytics, like:

```
2017-08-17 22:28:13.937301+0200 MuseON[34916:2139527] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
2017-08-17 22:28:13.937 MuseON[34916] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
2017-08-17 22:28:13.939874+0200 MuseON[34916:2135440] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
2017-08-17 22:28:13.939 MuseON[34916] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
```

Comment: " beta 1" stop and update. Beta 5 is current.

Comment: I'll update it tomorrow (I have a bad internet connection right now). Just asking if it's a known bug/a bug still present in new releases.

Comment: Tested with Xcode 9 beta 5 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like Firebase analytics works and the issue is with Firebase database. I think you should remove firebase-analytics tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: @adbitx The firebase-analytics tag was added in an external edit. I'll delete it.